# how to get firebase token?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I didn't program android for a while and i see the firebase messaging service got deprecated.
I implemented the new `FirebaseMessagingService` class and i have overridden the onNewToken in order to get the token, but the method is not even being called, as the documentation said this method should be ran automaticlly. but now i got confused, why the token is not generated? here is what i implemented

```
public class FireBsaeTest extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public FireBsaeTest(){
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

            } else {

            }

        }


        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        System.out.println(token);

    }}
```

and here is the manifest

```
 <service android:name=".FireBsaeTest">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

did i miss something ?

**UPDATE**

i tried to call it manually from my activity it thorw new Illegal exception firebaseNotInilized

```
 FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                System.out.println(instanceIdResult.getToken());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just knew where is the problem, the problem was the implementation of root `build.gradle` file with class-path, android studio configring the dependecies like the following

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

google-services should be configured   `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`
once i changed the class path it works and now im able to get the token

Answer (score 0):

**MyFirebaseMessagingService**

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();


        @Override
        public void onNewToken(String s) {
            super.onNewToken(s);
            Log.i(TAG, "onNewToken:    >>>  " + s);
        }
     @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
           }
    }
```

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java**

```
 public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
        @Override
        public void onTokenRefresh() {
            String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            Log.d("FirebaseInstanceID", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

            // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.

        }
    }
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
    <service   android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
 android:exported="false"
  android:stopWithTask="false">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
            <service
                    android:name=".services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
                    android:exported="false">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
```

**Gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was with class path, take a look at my answer